# Multi-variable indexes in postgres

Tags: database, postgresql, indexing

Im looking at an application where I will be doing quite a few `SELECT`s where I am trying to find `column_a = x AND column_b = y`.
Is the correct to create that index that something like the following?

```
CREATE INDEX index_name ON table (column_a, column_b)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Yes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-multicolumn.html).

Comment: Great, thanks. I searched the postgres documentation but didnt find anything like that.